# Prevent Spring Boot from holding file lock on static content

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot

From the spring boot [documentation on static content](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content):

"By default Spring Boot will serve static content from a folder called
`/static` (or `/public` or `/resources` or `/META-INF/resources)` in the
classpath or from the root of the ServeltContext [sic]"

To take advantage of this behavior, I added a `static` folder to `src/main/resources`.  Sure enough, Spring Boot serves up this static content.  It looks something like this in Eclipse:

[image]

Spring Boot must somehow hold a file lock on the static content once served, however, because whenever I change static content, I get an Eclipse project error like so:

[image]

I have to stop the application in order to get the project to build which is REALLY annoying!  Anybody have a solution to this?

Comment: I never had that problem. What platform are you on? Also the "bin" directory in that path is suspicious since it is used by Eclipse for "native" Java projects, but not by Maven or Gradle. Are you using Maven or Gradle, and if not why not?

Comment: Unfortunately this is a Windows platform.  The bin directory is interesting, and the Eclipse project is a Gradle project.  Of course, I'm simply allowing Eclipse to build the source and running it from there, not from Gradle.

Comment: I don't use the Eclipse Gradle tooling. Does it work if you run from the command line ("mvn spring-boot:run")?

Comment: It does, but then I can't debug the application in the usual way.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in `org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler` in spring-webmvc that is fixed with the latest tip.

This was the offending block of code that was using an `InputStream` plucked from `ClassPathResource` without closing it:

```
protected void writeContent(HttpServletResponse response, Resource resource) throws IOException {
    StreamUtils.copy(resource.getInputStream(), response.getOutputStream());
}
```

See https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11644 for the bug report.